# NodeJs delete request via jQuery/ajax

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax

I have this code on server side

```
 router.delete('/categories/delete/:id', function(req,res){
         var id = req.params.id;
          Category.remove({_id: id},function(err){
               if(err){
                    console.log(err);
               }
               req.flash('success','Category Deleted');
               res.location('/manage/categories');
               res.redirect('/manage/categories');
          });
    });
```

In dustjs view I have this button `<a href="#" class="removeCategory button tiny alert" data-id="{._id}">Delete</a>`

And in the script file i have

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.removeCategory').on('click', function(e){
        $target =  $(e.target);
        var id = $target.attr('data-id');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'DELETE',
            url: '/manage/categories/delete/'+id,
            success: function(response){
                alert('Delete');
                window.location = '/manage/categories';
            },
            error: function(err){
                console.log(err);
            }

        });
    });

});
```

The thing is that it kinda works but the category disappears only after I refresh the page but when i have  look at the console I get a message like this:

```
abort: function abort()
​
always: function always()
​
complete: function add()
​
done: function add()
​
error: function add()
​
fail: function add()
​
getAllResponseHeaders: function getAllResponseHeaders()
​
getResponseHeader: function getResponseHeader()
​
overrideMimeType: function overrideMimeType()
​
pipe: function then()
​
progress: function add()
​
promise: function promise()
​
readyState: 4
​
responseText: "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang=\"en\">\n<head>\n<meta charset=\"utf-8\">\n<title>Error</title>\n</head>\n<body>\n<pre>Cannot DELETE /manage/categories</pre>\n</body>\n</html>\n"
​
setRequestHeader: function setRequestHeader()
​
state: function state()
​
status: 404
​
statusCode: function statusCode()
​
statusText: "Not Found"
​
success: function add()
​
then: function then()
```

I also want to mention that the alert box never appears. Does anyone know how to fix this issue? Thank you in advance

Comment: What is the server side code? Which framework ?

Comment: It seems like you're not actually returning the response to the client from your server side, and that your `success` callback on the client isn't being triggered because of that.

Comment: Thank you for you opinion. I will have a  look on that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems like the url you are calling is not correct, the responseText property gives a hint on that:

```
Cannot DELETE /manage/categories
```

thats why your error Handler is called:

```
error: function(err){
  console.log(err);
}
```

and not the success.

Are you sure the id is determined correct?

Comment: Yes the id is correct and the link i access all the categories is: http://localhost:3000/manage/categories That s why the url is `/manage/categories/delete/'+id` to match the server side code and then i want to reload the page I m  using  `/manage/categories`  in window.location  If I don t refresh the page nothing happens, once i refresh after i clicked the button i get the flash message and the category goes away

Comment: I fixed it by removing the # from a link. I left it empty. You were right the link it was the problem apparently. Thank you for your answer

Comment: However I still get that message in console and the alert message never triggers, but I get the flash message and the category is removed

Comment: does this route supports the method 'delete' ?  can you send the part of your server side code where you process the response?

Comment: this is the server side code:  `router.delete('/categories/delete/:id', function(req,res){
         var id = req.params.id;
          Category.remove({_id: id},function(err){
               if(err){
                    console.log(err);
               }
               req.flash('success','Category Deleted');
               res.location('/manage/categories');
               res.redirect('/manage/categories');
          });
    });` In my main comment I displayed the server side code, dustjs code only that, now i removed the "#" from the anchor to make it work

Comment: as @gillyb wrote, try something like: res.send('Got a DELETE request at /user'); at the end

Comment: On the server side I added when i try to remove the category:
`if(err){
                   res.send('error');
                    
               } else{
                res.send('success');
               }` and on the front end script I added on the success function :
`success: function(response){
    if(response === 'error'){
     alert('error');
    } else if(response === 'success'){
     console.log('it worked');
     window.location.href = '/manage';
    }
    
   },` and still no message in the console. I guess I leave it like this.

Comment: I added a `complete` method right after `error`  method in front end script and in that method i added the `window.location` and the console and now I get the message in the console.